# Type "str" cannot be assigned to type "type[str]"

Tags: python, list, types

The method is:

```py
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        stringList = list(s)
        countList = [int]
        current = [str]
        actualCounting = 1
        for e1 in stringList:
            current.append(e1)
            for e2 in stringList:
                if (not current.count(e2)):
                    actualCounting += 1
                    current.append(e2)
                else:
                    countList.append(actualCounting)
                    actualCounting = 1
```

I am getting the following issue always when "e1" and "e2" appears:

> Argument of type "str" cannot be assigned to parameter "__value" of type "type[str]" in function "count"
>
> Type "str" cannot be assigned to type "type[str]"

I did not even finish this method since this is incomplete and has no return, but this hint/issue is making me lose my mind.

I can’t understand what means "type[str]", it looks like a type of strings ?
If `current` is a list of str, every value into is str as well, so it must not complain when I put a value of current where it expect a "str".

I want to make my code typed, every variable with their types to see the hints and make sure the types are going well to where they should.
If I remove "str" in

```
current = [str]
```

The issue is solved but my list loses his type and as I said, I want to keep the "type control".

Comment: _of type "type[str]" in function "count"_ The error appears to refer to a function `count()` which you have not shown us...

Comment: Do you really want to create a list where first element is a type? What should it mean?

Comment: @John It's referring to `list.count()`

Comment: @wjandrea Ah, I see.

Comment: Yes, `type[str]` means `str` itself, because that's what you set: `current = [str]`. It looks like you meant `current: list[str] = []` instead. You should do a tutorial on typing, because Stack Overflow isn't built to teach the basics.

Comment: As others have said, `current = [str]` is **not** the right way to say "current is a list of string values".

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to declare variable type, C style in Python](/q/3933197/4518341), or more specifically, [Define a list with type](/q/1924469/4518341)

Comment: Is that the full error message? Usually there is a full traceback showing the failing line and how it was called.

Comment: I don't see how the code you've shown produces that error. I took the `self` argument out and called it with "hello there" and did not have a problem. You'll have to show us something reproducable.

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking for type hints. Python is a dynamically typed language, so the language is designed so that types of variables are not explicitly declared like in Java or C++.

You should change:

```
countList = [int]
current = [str]
```

to

```
countList: list[int] = []
current: list[str] = []
```

You can then use a third-party typechecker, like mypy, to verify that the type of each variable is what you expect. These type hints don’t alter runtime behavior.